# Are there any well-understood circumstances when we should expect cross-validation to be indifferent to $\alpha$ in elastic net tuning?

Tags: cross-validation, glmnet

I am fitting a lot of elastic net models, simultaneously tuning $\lambda$ and $\alpha$. I am often coming to the following conclusions:

- Cross-validation error is much more sensitive to changes in $\lambda$ than $\alpha$
- In fact, the differences in cross-validation error are negligible between $L_1$, $L_2$, and $\alpha$ = 0.5

Without looking at my data or knowing anything about it, even the family of GLM I'm using, are there any generalizable results about the conditions when this would be the case?

Thank you.

Comment: just to make sure, by cross-validation error you mean the error from nested cross validation? Because if you choose $\lambda$ by CV you need an outer loop to have a realistic prediction error.

Comment: I am merely talking about the prediction error measures used to optimize $\lambda$ and $\alpha$. Not the measure of prediction error once lambda and alpha have been optimized.

Comment: if you run a ridge regresion and a lasso regression separately,does one outperform the other?

Comment: As I state in the question, no, and then I ask if there are any general cases when we would not expect the two to outperform one another.